# Copy worksheets based on column value

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new with Excel vba but have been using access vba for some time now.

I have some code which splits a main file into several other files based on a distinct column in excel

```
Sub SplitbyValue()
   Dim FromR As Range, ToR As Range, All As Range, Header As Range
   Dim Wb As Workbook
   Dim Ws As Worksheet
  'Get the header in this sheet
   Set Header = Range("D8").EntireRow

  'Visit each used cell in column D, except the header
   Set FromR = Range("D9")
   For Each ToR In Range(FromR, Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1))
     'Did the value change?
     If FromR <> ToR Then
       'Yes, get the cells between
       Set All = Range(FromR, ToR.Offset(-1)).EntireRow
       'Make a new file



       Set Wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
        'Copy the data into there


       With Wb.ActiveSheet
         Header.Copy .Range("A8")
         All.Copy .Range("A9")
       End With
       'Save it


       Wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Date, "yyyy.mm.dd") & _
         " - " & FromR.Value & ".xls", xlWorkbookNormal
       Wb.Close
       'Remember the start of this section
       Set FromR = ToR
     End If
   Next
 End Sub
```

This works great for the main sheet, but have to copy multiple tabs and this only captures one sheet. How can I expand this so it copies the other sheets as well into that file?

example:
ColumnA
Id1
Id2
Id3

This creates three files (Id1)(Id2)(Id3) but ignores the other sheets.

Comment: You need a `For Each (sheet variable) in (Workbook variable).Sheets` loop around your entire thing. Right now it is only doing whichever sheet is active when you start the macro.

Answer (score 1):

Create an encompassing loop and define the worksheet being processed with a [With...End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). You loop through a [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) using a [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224506(v=office.11).aspx) on the [Worksheets collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508(v=office.11).aspx) but I typically use the index of each worksheet.

```
Sub SplitbyValue()
    Dim FromR As Range, ToR As Range, dta As Range, hdr As Range
    Dim w As Long, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, nuwb As Workbook

    'Get the header in this sheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    For w = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        With wb.Worksheets(w)
            Set hdr = .Range(.Cells(8, "D"), .Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

            'Visit each used cell in column D, except the header
            Set FromR = .Range("D9")
            For Each ToR In .Range(FromR, .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1))
                'Did the value change?
                If FromR <> ToR Then
                    'Yes, get the cells between
                    Set dta = .Range(FromR, ToR.Offset(-1)).EntireRow

                    'Make a new file
                    Set nuwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

                    'Copy the data into there
                    With nuwb.Sheet1
                         hdr.Copy .Range("A8")
                         dta.Copy .Range("A9")
                    End With

                    'Save it
                    nuwb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Date, "yyyy.mm.dd") & _
                        " - " & FromR.Value & ".xls", xlWorkbookNormal
                    nuwb.Close False
                    Set nuwb = Nothing

                    'Remember the start of this section
                    Set FromR = ToR
                End If
            Next ToR

        End With
    Next w
End Sub
```

I did not set up a full test environment but this should get you heading in the right direction. I've always found it unreliable to depend on ActiveSheet.

Comment: Tried this out but sadly didnt work:

I get a "Run-time error '438':
Object doesnt support this property or method

Going to be playing with this code a little  so ill update shorly

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will allow you to search for a sheet and goto it by name.

```
 Private Sub loopsheets(strSheetName As String)
    iFoundWorksheet = 0
    For iIndex = 1 To ea.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set ws = ea.Worksheets(iIndex)
        If UCase(ws.Name) = UCase(strSheetName) Then
            iFoundWorksheet = iIndex
            Exit For
        End If
    Next iIndex
    If iFoundWorksheet = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No worksheet was found with the name RESULTS (this is not case sensetive). Aborting."
    End If
    Set ws = ea.Worksheets(iFoundWorksheet)
    ws.Activate

End Sub
```

If you want to just loop them all you just need the for loop.

```
    Dim iIndex as Integer
    For iIndex = 1 To ea.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set ws = ea.Worksheets(iIndex)
        ws.Activate

        'Call your code here.
        SplitbyValue

    Next iIndex
```